# Find Unknown coefficient using Contour plot

Tags: plotting, interpolation, coefficients

I have I really complicated equation, but for simplicity lets assume my function is F(x,y,z)= a*x+b*y+c*z, where a, b and c are some unknown constants.

From experiments we know that at:

x=3, y=2, z=1 then F=10

x=2, y=1, z=0 then F=4

x=1, y=0, z=0 then F=1

So, is there any way to plot F(x,y,z) as contour plot and then fit my data above in order to extract the exact unknown coefficient?

By the way the example answer is a=1, b=2 and c=3.

Comment: for the example posted, you can use `{a, b, c} = LinearSolve[data[[All, ;; 3]], data[[All, -1]]]` or `{a, b, c} = LeastSquares[data[[All, ;; 3]], data[[All, -1]]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_, z_] = a*x + b*y + c*z;
```

Your data is the form `{x, y, z, f}`

```
data = {{3, 2, 1, 10}, {2, 1, 0, 4}, {1, 0, 0, 1}};
```

Each set of the data generates one equation

```
eqns = f @@ Most[#] == Last@# & /@ data

(* {3 a + 2 b + c == 10, 2 a + b == 4, a == 1} *)
```

There are three equations and three unknown coefficients; consequently, the system can be solved

```
sol = Solve[eqns, {a, b, c}][[1]]

(* {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3} *)
```

The form of the function is

```
f[x, y, z] /. sol

(* x + 2 y + 3 z *)
```

Comment: Since my data are experimental (more than three points) and with complicated relation I was unable to solve it using system of equation. That's why if this problem can be solved using contour plot or in any other graphical technique ?

Comment: If you can make a plot you must have a model. Is there something that prevents you from using [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) to fit your data to that model?